# How to programatically access appenders from logback-access config?

Tags: logback

I have enabled logback-access log for Tomcat 7.0, using LogbackValve.
My logback-access config looks like this.

```
<configuration>  
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>access.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>access.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>combined</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</configuration>
```

Now this works perfect and I can see access logs. But in some other code I want to retrieve the appender configured in logback-access.xml programmatically. Is there a way to do it. Since there are no Loggers defined , you cannot use LoggerContext .

Answer (score 0):

You can use LogbackAccessContext to retrieve the appenders configured in logback-access.xml. This is my solution:

```java
TomcatServletWebServerFactory sc = (TomcatServletWebServerFactory) context.getBean(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.class);
List<Valve> values = (List<Valve>) sc.getEngineValves();
LogbackAccessTomcatValve accessTomcatValve = null;
for(Valve value : values) {
    if(value.getClass() == LogbackAccessTomcatValve.class) {
        accessTomcatValve = (LogbackAccessTomcatValve) value;
    }
}

//get logbackAccessContext from the logbackAccessTomcatValve by invoking.
LogbackAccessContext logbackAccessContext = null;
Field field = null;
try {
    field = accessTomcatValve.getClass().getDeclaredField("logbackAccessContext");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    logbackAccessContext = (LogbackAccessContext) field.get(accessTomcatValve);
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Exception happened when fetching the logback access context ." +e.getMessage());
}
```